# can I resolve a deadlock with the rowlock hint?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, deadlock, delete, lock-escalation

I have a large delete stored proc and I've reproduced a deadlock in a situation where the deletes would not have deleted anything.

It looks like the part of the stored proc that hit a deadlock was like this (changed table names):

```
DELETE d
FROM Table1 d
inner join dbo.Table2 orc on orc.id = d.Table2Id
inner join dbo.Table3 orr on orr.id = orc.Table3Id
inner join Table4 oeh on oeh.id = orr.Table4Id
inner join @deleteEntities de on de.id = oeh.EntityId
```

It looks to me like two deletes were running at the same time and deadlock each other when trying to delete from this large table. For these items I know that there would have been no records very large tables table1, table2, table3.

I am wondering if this might be fixed by changing to:

```
DELETE d
FROM Table1 d WITH(rowlock)
inner join dbo.Table2 orc on orc.id = d.Table2Id
inner join dbo.Table3 orr on orr.id = orc.Table3Id
inner join Table4 oeh on oeh.id = orr.Table4Id
inner join @deleteEntities de on de.id = oeh.EntityId
```

I am thinking that since table1 is a large table sql-server locks whole pages and this hint will make it only lock rows. Note that I have indexed fk's on Table2Id, Table3Id, Table4Id and entityid.

I have enabled tracing as described here:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160206200456/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/bartd/archive/2006/09/09/deadlock-troubleshooting_2c00_-part-1.aspx)

with:

```
DBCC TRACEON (1222, -1)
```

Below is the log output with "2011-08-29 15:46:57.78 spid15s" cut off the start of each line. From what I see two usp_EntityFullDelete's are deadlocking on the same statement - one deleting row 746946 and one deleting row 628302. Am I correct in my analysis of this trace output? Is there anything else that might help prevent this?

```
deadlock-list
 deadlock victim=process3e9ada8
  process-list
   process id=processbaf048 taskpriority=0 logused=20022 waittime=3890 schedulerid=1 kpid=1304 status=suspended spid=59 sbid=0 ecid=1 priority=0 transcount=0 lastbatchstarted=2011-08-29T15:46:53.263 lastbatchcompleted=2011-08-29T15:46:53.263 clientapp=.Net SqlClient Data Provider hostname=RGDS hostpid=9108 isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=1135559188 currentdb=19 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671088672 clientoption2=128056
    executionStack
     frame procname=Bugfixes.dbo.usp_EntityFullDelete line=178 stmtstart=11180 stmtend=11776 sqlhandle=0x030013007b725817b4bfe400499f00000100000000000000
DELETE d
FROM Table1 d
    inner join dbo.Table2 orc on orc.id = d.Table2Id
    inner join dbo.Table3 orr on orr.id = orc.Table3Id
    inner join Table4 oeh on oeh.id = orr.Table4Id
    inner join @deleteEntities de on de.id = oeh.EntityId     
     frame procname=adhoc line=1 sqlhandle=0x01001300ef337933809a04fd000000000000000000000000
exec dbo.usp_EntityFullDelete 746946,0     
    inputbuf
   process id=processbaf588 taskpriority=0 logused=20022 waittime=3906 schedulerid=1 kpid=6244 status=suspended spid=62 sbid=0 ecid=3 priority=0 transcount=0 lastbatchstarted=2011-08-29T15:46:45.637 lastbatchcompleted=2011-08-29T15:46:45.637 clientapp=.Net SqlClient Data Provider hostname=RGDS hostpid=9108 isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=1135558120 currentdb=19 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671088672 clientoption2=128056
    executionStack
     frame procname=Bugfixes.dbo.usp_EntityFullDelete line=178 stmtstart=11180 stmtend=11776 sqlhandle=0x030013007b725817b4bfe400499f00000100000000000000
DELETE d
FROM Table1 d
    inner join dbo.Table2 orc on orc.id = d.Table2Id
    inner join dbo.Table3 orr on orr.id = orc.Table3Id
    inner join Table4 oeh on oeh.id = orr.Table4Id
    inner join @deleteEntities de on de.id = oeh.EntityId     
     frame procname=adhoc line=1 sqlhandle=0x01001300fc3e1016609402c4000000000000000000000000
exec dbo.usp_EntityFullDelete 628302,0     
    inputbuf
   process id=process3e9a868 taskpriority=0 logused=580 waitresource=PAGE: 19:1:1942004 waittime=3890 ownerId=1135558120 transactionname=user_transaction lasttranstarted=2011-08-29T15:46:53.053 XDES=0xf2512b30 lockMode=U schedulerid=3 kpid=8808 status=suspended spid=62 sbid=0 ecid=8 priority=0 transcount=0 lastbatchstarted=2011-08-29T15:46:45.637 lastbatchcompleted=2011-08-29T15:46:45.637 clientapp=.Net SqlClient Data Provider hostname=RGDS hostpid=9108 isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=1135558120 currentdb=19 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671088672 clientoption2=128056
    executionStack
     frame procname=Bugfixes.dbo.usp_EntityFullDelete line=178 stmtstart=11180 stmtend=11776 sqlhandle=0x030013007b725817b4bfe400499f00000100000000000000
DELETE d
FROM Table1 d
    inner join dbo.Table2 orc on orc.id = d.Table2Id
    inner join dbo.Table3 orr on orr.id = orc.Table3Id
    inner join Table4 oeh on oeh.id = orr.Table4Id
    inner join @deleteEntities de on de.id = oeh.EntityId     
     frame procname=adhoc line=1 sqlhandle=0x01001300fc3e1016609402c4000000000000000000000000
exec dbo.usp_EntityFullDelete 628302,0     
    inputbuf
   process id=process3e9ada8 taskpriority=0 logused=0 waitresource=PAGE: 19:1:1928384 waittime=3765 ownerId=1135559188 transactionname=user_transaction lasttranstarted=2011-08-29T15:46:53.263 XDES=0xf2512d70 lockMode=U schedulerid=3 kpid=9196 status=suspended spid=59 sbid=0 ecid=6 priority=0 transcount=0 lastbatchstarted=2011-08-29T15:46:53.263 lastbatchcompleted=2011-08-29T15:46:53.263 clientapp=.Net SqlClient Data Provider hostname=RGDS hostpid=9108 isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=1135559188 currentdb=19 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671088672 clientoption2=128056
    executionStack
     frame procname=Bugfixes.dbo.usp_EntityFullDelete line=178 stmtstart=11180 stmtend=11776 sqlhandle=0x030013007b725817b4bfe400499f00000100000000000000
DELETE d
FROM Table1 d
    inner join dbo.Table2 orc on orc.id = d.Table2Id
    inner join dbo.Table3 orr on orr.id = orc.Table3Id
    inner join Table4 oeh on oeh.id = orr.Table4Id
    inner join @deleteEntities de on de.id = oeh.EntityId     
     frame procname=adhoc line=1 sqlhandle=0x01001300ef337933809a04fd000000000000000000000000
exec dbo.usp_EntityFullDelete 746946,0     
    inputbuf
   process id=process3e9b198 taskpriority=0 logused=20006 waittime=3984 schedulerid=3 kpid=9212 status=suspended spid=59 sbid=0 ecid=0 priority=0 transcount=2 lastbatchstarted=2011-08-29T15:46:53.263 lastbatchcompleted=2011-08-29T15:46:53.263 clientapp=.Net SqlClient Data Provider hostname=RGDS hostpid=9108 loginname=sa isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=1135559188 currentdb=19 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671088672 clientoption2=128056
    executionStack
     frame procname=Bugfixes.dbo.usp_EntityFullDelete line=178 stmtstart=11180 stmtend=11776 sqlhandle=0x030013007b725817b4bfe400499f00000100000000000000
DELETE d
FROM Table1 d
    inner join dbo.Table2 orc on orc.id = d.Table2Id
    inner join dbo.Table3 orr on orr.id = orc.Table3Id
    inner join Table4 oeh on oeh.id = orr.Table4Id
    inner join @deleteEntities de on de.id = oeh.EntityId     
     frame procname=adhoc line=1 sqlhandle=0x01001300ef337933809a04fd000000000000000000000000
exec dbo.usp_EntityFullDelete 746946,0     
    inputbuf
exec dbo.usp_EntityFullDelete 746946,0    
   process id=process46b0da8 taskpriority=0 logused=20006 waittime=4000 schedulerid=4 kpid=6596 status=suspended spid=62 sbid=0 ecid=0 priority=0 transcount=2 lastbatchstarted=2011-08-29T15:46:45.637 lastbatchcompleted=2011-08-29T15:46:45.637 clientapp=.Net SqlClient Data Provider hostname=RGDS hostpid=9108 loginname=sa isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=1135558120 currentdb=19 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671088672 clientoption2=128056
    executionStack
     frame procname=Bugfixes.dbo.usp_EntityFullDelete line=178 stmtstart=11180 stmtend=11776 sqlhandle=0x030013007b725817b4bfe400499f00000100000000000000
DELETE d
FROM Table1 d
    inner join dbo.Table2 orc on orc.id = d.Table2Id
    inner join dbo.Table3 orr on orr.id = orc.Table3Id
    inner join Table4 oeh on oeh.id = orr.Table4Id
    inner join @deleteEntities de on de.id = oeh.EntityId     
     frame procname=adhoc line=1 sqlhandle=0x01001300fc3e1016609402c4000000000000000000000000
exec dbo.usp_EntityFullDelete 628302,0     
    inputbuf
exec dbo.usp_EntityFullDelete 628302,0    
   process id=process46b1048 taskpriority=0 logused=0 waitresource=PAGE: 19:1:1942003 waittime=3937 ownerId=1135559188 transactionname=user_transaction lasttranstarted=2011-08-29T15:46:53.263 XDES=0xd0224ab0 lockMode=U schedulerid=4 kpid=7892 status=suspended spid=59 sbid=0 ecid=8 priority=0 transcount=0 lastbatchstarted=2011-08-29T15:46:53.263 lastbatchcompleted=2011-08-29T15:46:53.263 clientapp=.Net SqlClient Data Provider hostname=RGDS hostpid=9108 isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=1135559188 currentdb=19 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671088672 clientoption2=128056
    executionStack
     frame procname=Bugfixes.dbo.usp_EntityFullDelete line=178 stmtstart=11180 stmtend=11776 sqlhandle=0x030013007b725817b4bfe400499f00000100000000000000
DELETE d
FROM Table1 d
    inner join dbo.Table2 orc on orc.id = d.Table2Id
    inner join dbo.Table3 orr on orr.id = orc.Table3Id
    inner join Table4 oeh on oeh.id = orr.Table4Id
    inner join @deleteEntities de on de.id = oeh.EntityId     
     frame procname=adhoc line=1 sqlhandle=0x01001300ef337933809a04fd000000000000000000000000
exec dbo.usp_EntityFullDelete 746946,0     
    inputbuf
   process id=process46b16d8 taskpriority=0 logused=580 waitresource=PAGE: 19:1:441708 waittime=3937 ownerId=1135558120 transactionname=user_transaction lasttranstarted=2011-08-29T15:46:53.053 XDES=0xd0224870 lockMode=U schedulerid=4 kpid=6676 status=suspended spid=62 sbid=0 ecid=6 priority=0 transcount=0 lastbatchstarted=2011-08-29T15:46:45.637 lastbatchcompleted=2011-08-29T15:46:45.637 clientapp=.Net SqlClient Data Provider hostname=RGDS hostpid=9108 isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=1135558120 currentdb=19 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671088672 clientoption2=128056
    executionStack
     frame procname=Bugfixes.dbo.usp_EntityFullDelete line=178 stmtstart=11180 stmtend=11776 sqlhandle=0x030013007b725817b4bfe400499f00000100000000000000
DELETE d
FROM Table1 d
    inner join dbo.Table2 orc on orc.id = d.Table2Id
    inner join dbo.Table3 orr on orr.id = orc.Table3Id
    inner join Table4 oeh on oeh.id = orr.Table4Id
    inner join @deleteEntities de on de.id = oeh.EntityId     
     frame procname=adhoc line=1 sqlhandle=0x01001300fc3e1016609402c4000000000000000000000000
exec dbo.usp_EntityFullDelete 628302,0     
    inputbuf
  resource-list
   pagelock fileid=1 pageid=1928384 dbid=19 objectname=Bugfixes.dbo.Table1 id=lockaef9db80 mode=U associatedObjectId=72057595211284480
    owner-list
     owner id=process46b0da8 mode=U
    waiter-list
     waiter id=process3e9ada8 mode=U requestType=wait
   exchangeEvent id=port80128a00 nodeId=22
    owner-list
     owner event=e_waitNone type=producer id=process3e9ada8
     owner event=e_waitNone type=producer id=process46b1048
    waiter-list
     waiter event=e_waitPortClose type=consumer id=processbaf048
   exchangeEvent id=port80128e20 nodeId=6
    owner-list
     owner event=e_waitNone type=producer id=processbaf048
    waiter-list
     waiter event=e_waitPortOpen type=consumer id=process3e9b198
   pagelock fileid=1 pageid=1942004 dbid=19 objectname=Bugfixes.dbo.Table1 id=lockf3d1f080 mode=U associatedObjectId=72057595211284480
    owner-list
     owner id=process3e9b198 mode=U
    waiter-list
     waiter id=process3e9a868 mode=U requestType=wait
   exchangeEvent id=port80128ed0 nodeId=22
    owner-list
     owner event=e_waitNone type=producer id=process46b16d8
     owner event=e_waitNone type=producer id=process3e9a868
    waiter-list
     waiter event=e_waitPortClose type=consumer id=processbaf588
   exchangeEvent id=port80128320 nodeId=6
    owner-list
     owner event=e_waitNone type=producer id=processbaf588
    waiter-list
     waiter event=e_waitPortOpen type=consumer id=process46b0da8
   pagelock fileid=1 pageid=1942003 dbid=19 objectname=Bugfixes.dbo.Table1 id=lockfbcc1680 mode=U associatedObjectId=72057595211284480
    owner-list
     owner id=process46b0da8 mode=U
    waiter-list
     waiter id=process46b1048 mode=U requestType=wait
   pagelock fileid=1 pageid=441708 dbid=19 objectname=Bugfixes.dbo.Table1 id=lockfc628980 mode=U associatedObjectId=72057595211284480
    owner-list
     owner id=process3e9b198 mode=U
    waiter-list
     waiter id=process46b16d8 mode=U requestType=wait
```

Comment: This is part of a larger transaction - we don't want only half the data to be deleted. The time of the whole thing varies but for this item it may have been about 10 seconds. There is conditional logic - eg. a flag is passed in to tell it to also delete some extra items - would removing condition make any difference? Would changing to where exists make any difference?

Comment: Not sure, would need to see more details. Can you post the whole procedure instead of just the delete statement?

Answer (score 4):

Deleted my previous answer when I realised the trace shows parallelism.

With a big warning to test this very very thoroughly, you might alleviate the deadlocks by restricting MAXDOP and adding a UPDLOCK hint on Table1. I would also (as per @Aaron's suggestion) try EXISTS.

```
DELETE 
    d
FROM 
    Table1 d WITH (UPDLOCK)
INNER JOIN
    #deleteEntities de
ON  de.id = oeh.EntityId 
WHERE EXISTS
    (
    SELECT
        NULL
    FROM
        dbo.Table2 orc 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Table3 orr 
    ON  orr.id = orc.Table3Id
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.Table4 oeh            
    ON  oeh.id = orr.Table4Id
    WHERE
        oeh.id = de.Table2Id
    ) OPTION (MAXDOP 1, RECOMPILE)
```

This would be the sledgehammer approach. It's likely you could eliminate the parallelism with appropriate indexing but can't advise on that unless we see an execution plan and or statistics.

@deleteEntities in the deadlock trace is a little "suspicious". You're passing in a single identifer but have this temporary table in there?. Optimiser is likely to be producing an execution plan that estimates 1 for this, so if it contains a variable number of rows I'd switch to temporary table and force recompile (as above).

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server can still choose to escalate the row lock to a table lock, even if WITH(ROWLOCK) is specified.  This can depend on a number of things including:  number of rows deleted, number of total locks acquired by transaction, and total memory pressure of all locks acquired.

Sunil Agarwal has written a great article describing this process, which can be found here:  [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160111021224/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/05/17/lock-escalation.aspx)

One thing you can do to alleviate the impact of these DELETE statements is to perform the deletes in chunks:

```
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    DELETE TOP(5000)
    FROM <table>
    WHERE <condition>

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        BREAK;
    END
END
```

Unfortunately, the answer to your original question is a big fat "It Depends".

**EDIT (Adding Query to look at lock information):**

```
SELECT
    DB_NAME([tl].[resource_database_id]) AS [database_name],
    SCHEMA_NAME([o].[schema_id]) + '.' + [o].[name] AS [object_name],
    [tl].[request_type],
    [tl].[request_mode],
    [tl].[request_status]
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions AS [es]

    INNER JOIN sys.dm_tran_locks AS [tl]
        ON [es].[session_id] = [tl].[request_session_id]    

        INNER JOIN sys.objects AS [o]
            ON [tl].[resource_associated_entity_id] = [o].[object_id]
        
WHERE [es].[is_user_process] = 1;
```

I hope this "almost answer" helps,

Matt